# How do you set a variable to be an empty, but workable Jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Outside of a for I declare a variable using `var list;`.  I use this variable inside of my for loop like so:

```
// add the html to the list
if (list == undefined)
    list = item;
else
    list.append(item.contents());
```

`item` is a cloned jquery object build from a `$('list_template').clone();` call (list_template is a div with `<li>` elements inside).  What I am doing is creating a list, which I will then appendTo() where I need it.

Right now this code works fine, but it doesn't seem right to me.  Unfortunatly, I cannot seem to figure out how to correctly declare the `list` variable to be an empty Jquery object.  I have tried both:

```
var list = $([]);
var list = $('');
```

Both of those cause the append to not work correctly (or as expected) with list.html() being null.  Is there a way to initialize my variable to an empty jquery object, so all I have to do is `list.append(item.contents());` without the if/else statements?

---

**Edit:** Ok to lessen confusion here is the whole javascript function that currently works fine:

```
        var list;

        // Loop through all of the objects
        var objects = data.objects;
        for (x = 0; x < objects.length; x++) {
            // Clone the object list item template
            var item = $("#object_item_list_template").clone();

            // Setup the click action and inner text for the link tag in the template
            item.find('a').bind('click', { val: objects[x].Id }, function (e) { ShowObjectDetails(e.data.val); })
                          .html(objects[x].Name);

            // add the html to the list
            if (list == undefined)
                list = item;
            else
                list.append(item.contents());
        }
        // set the list of the topics to the topic list
        $("#object_list").empty();
        $('<ul>').appendTo("#object_list").append(list.contents());
```

The object list template is as follows:

```
<div id="object_item_list_template" style="display:none">
    <li class="object_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
</div>
```

This all works correctly by cloning the list item, setting up the click action, and adding it to the list on the display.

I am trying to get rid of the if/else statement.  I can't just do list.append() because if list is undefined (or not a Jquery object), it throws an exception.

Comment: It sounds like you want a string, or a temporary element, an empty list still won't do what you're after here, since `.append()` is called *on the matched elements*, of which there won't be any...also a `<div>` cannot contain a `<li>`, only a `<ul>` or `<ol>` can...can you provide the markup you're working with?

Comment: The code I posted does work correctly.  After I build the full list I then perform a $('#blah').append(list.contents()) and all of the list's markup and bindings correctly get displayed on the screen.  I do not need a string because I am putting jquery click handlers onto links inside of the item jquery object, and thus cannot use straight html and need to use a jquery object.

Comment: @Kall - `.append()` appends text to each of the elements in the jQuery collection...since you won't have any elements you're adding to nothing, and `.contents()` will be empty at the end. jQuery isn't an element, it's a wrapper around references to (an array of) DOM elements...having an empty array won't help, you've seen this by trying `$([])`.  Currently you're taking the first element and appending **inside it**, not **beside/after it**...inspect the result, I don't think it's what you're after, you have a single item in the end with all others inside, not a list.

Comment: Updated question to show more code.

Comment: You can `push()` new elements into a jQuery object. I'll update my answer.

Comment: As @Nick Craver suggested in his comments, you could always just make `list` into a `ul`, and append items to that. Perhaps he'll add an answer, as it is probably a better solution. :o)

Comment: Actually that's not a bad idea to just use a $('<ul>').  Not really sure why I didn't do that in the first place.

Comment: Probably a better solution. Since you already know what the container is ultimately going to be, no need to use an empty object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty jQuery object is declared as:

```
$();
```

Docs for jQuery object creation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

---

**EDIT:**

It sounds like you're trying to eliminate the `if/else` statement by extending `list` whether or not it has any content.

Is that right?

If so, try something like this:

```
list = $( list.get().concat(item.get()) );
```

or

```
$.extend(list, item);
```

(Assumes `list` is starting out as an empty jQuery object.)

---

**EDIT:**

Since you're creating elements in a loop, you can always `push()` then into a jQuery object.

Try something like this:

```
var list = $();  // Start off with empty jQuery object.

...

list.push(item.find('li').get(0));  // A jQuery object is an Array. You can `push()` new items (DOM elements) in.

...

('<ul>').appendTo("#object_list").append(list);
```

(I edited from the original to only push the DOM element into the jQuery object.)

Should add the current item in the loop to your list.

You could eliminate the `find()` calls in your code if you just cloned the children of `#object_item_list_template`:

```
$('li', '#object_item_list_template').clone();  // Clone the `li` without the `div`.
```

Now you have a clone of the `li` itself. No need to do a find.

Comment: I think what he needs is `list = $("<ul />")`, `.append()` the items, then `$("#destination").append(list.contents());`, something along those lines...but I can't be 100% sure from the question, there's a few invalid things going on as I noted in comments.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Yeah, the `li` elements in the `div` isn't right (though they do show up in Firefox anyway), and the `append()` isn't right, but I think the gist of the question is that he wants to eliminate the `if/else` by extending `list`, whether it be from an empty jQuery object, or a populated one. You're right, a little odd and tough tell what is intended.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't realize jquery objects are arrays.  I'll give this a shot when I get home!

Comment: Why do you do a .get(0) on the .find?  If use get instead of pushing the results of .find() will it maintain all javascript/jquery bindings on the inside elements (that was the main reason for me not to copy the html inside, because the javascript bindings would be lost)?

Comment: @KallDrexx - Because DOM elements need to be pushed in. The `.get()` pulls the DOM element out of the `.find()` result. I believe that your `click` event (and its data) will be maintained.